# How to check if a menu is displayed

Tags: apache-flex

I create a menu with this:

```
menu = Menu.createMenu(parent, get_entries());
                    menu.labelField = "@label";
                    ...
        menu.show(position.x, position.y);
```

How can to check if the menu is still displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to the [menuHide](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Menu.html#event:menuHide) event of the `menu`; it is dispatched when the menu or a submenu is hidden. Inside the event listener, check if `event.target == event.currentTarget`. If they are equal, it means that the menu was just hidden - otherwise it means that the menu is still visible, but one of its submenus were just hidden.

```
menu.addEventListener(MeuEvent.MENU_HIDE, onHide);
private function onHide(e:Event):void
{
  if(e.target == e.currentTarget)
    trace("The main menu was just hidden");
  else
    trace("main menu is still visible, the submenu " 
            + e.target + " was just hidden");
}
```